# Citeproc and Pandoc Fignos conflicts with `@` in Pandoc?

Tags: pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

I am using the latest version [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-citations) to convert MD to LaTex to PDF, with `citeproc: true` in the Defaults file. Additionally, I am using [pandoc-xnos](https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-xnos) to reference figures.

The problem appears to be their similar syntax. Near any `@` seems to trigger CiteProc, and Pandoc Xnos requires `@fig:id` to reference files. Everything generates, although Citeproc generates warnings for each xnos reference (`[WARNING] Citeproc: citation fig:id not found`) and surrounds each Figure reference with `[]` as it does links.

Has anyone found a way to merge these two better? Ideally, Citeproc would only generate with `[@cite]` and xnox only with `{@cite}`, or recognize `@fig:` is not a typical citation, or the like, but reading over the documentation of both I cannot find an option or solution.

Comment: from https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-xnos#usage: "Any use of --filter pandoc-citeproc or --bibliography=FILE should come after the pandoc-xnos filter call."

Answer (score 2):

Adding `citeproc: true` to the defaults file will run citeproc as one of the first filters. You can control filter order in the defaults file by removing the `citeproc` setting and define the `filters` sequence like so:

```yaml
# these filters run in the defined order
filters:
  - type: json
    path: pandoc-xnos
  - type: citeproc
```

Older versions of pandoc contain a small bug which require to add an arbitrary path to the citeproc entry:

```yaml
  - type: citeproc
    path: does not matter
```